# Decode Argon2 parameters and handling decode errors

Tags: error-handling, go

I am writing a function to decode Argon2 hashed string to extract parameters. I need to handle many decode errors, and handle those errors lead to write many repeating `if err == nil` check code. Is there a better way to do this kind of check?

The encodedHash string follows the format, separated by `$`

```
"$argon2id$v=%d$m=%d,t=%d,p=%d$%s$%s"
```

so an example string looks like

```
$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=3,p=4$ruDgwQK24h0wGXI87+lVWAbHmgNidUNPVSTdSloOlfM$py20HR7L4K6LllGsZNDbkrbh89x2tIF8JCIG0DAaoi8
```

What the decode function do is convert the string into this struct

```
type Argon2Params struct {
    Memory     uint32
    Time       uint32
    Threads    uint8
    SaltLength uint32
    KeyLength  uint32
}
```

Here is the decode function, I need to do a serious check during the decoding process. Every filed need to be checked to make sure no error rises.

```
func decodeHash(encodedHash string) (p *Params, salt, hash []byte, err error) {
    fileds := strings.Split(encodedHash, "$")
    if len(fileds) != 6 {
        return nil, nil, nil, errors.New("The encoded hash is not in the correct format")
    }

    var version int
// error check
    if _, err = fmt.Sscanf(fileds[2], "v=%d", &version); err != nil {
        return
    }
// error check
    if version != argon2.Version {
        return nil, nil, nil, errors.New("Argon2 version not match")
    }

    p = &Params{}
    _, err = fmt.Sscanf(fileds[3], "m=%d,t=%d,p=%d", &p.memory, &p.time, &p.threads)
// error check
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    salt, p.saltLength, err = decodeBase64WithLength(fileds[4])
// error check
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
// error check
    hash, p.keyLength, err = decodeBase64WithLength(fileds[5])
    return
}
// a helper function
func decodeBase64WithLength(encodeString string) (str []byte, length uint32, err error) {
    str, err = base64.RawStdEncoding.DecodeString(encodeString)
    length = uint32(len(str))
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use named parameters, the error checking can indeed be simplified.

While you critique the use of `if err != nil`, I enjoy the consistent error handling, and prefer it to the concepts used in many other languages.

### Returning errors

Rather than explicitly returning values, such as

```
return nil, nil, nil, errors.New("...")
```

You can instead set the named return value `err`:

```
if len(fields) != 6 {
    err = errors.New("incorrect hash format")
    return
}
```

This does not set the other values to `nil`, and that shouldn't matter. In terms of consuming this API, it would be bad practice to use any other return values if `err` is not `nil`. It would be the equivalent in C of using the return value of `strtoul()` without checking `errno`.

Having the comment `// error check` each time is too verbose.

### Misspelling

The variable `fileds` is misspelled, it should be `fields`.

### Helper function

Using named return values in your helper function is superfluous. You can easily return those variables directly.

```
func decodeBase64WithLength(encStr string) ([]byte, uint32, error) {
    s, err := base64.RawStdEncoding.DecodeString(encStr)
    return s, uint32(len(s)), err
}
```

But now that the function has been cleaned up, it's easy to see that it really isn't needed. If this is the only place you use the function, then doing something small twice doesn't justify a helper function in my opinion.

### `Params`

You reference `Argon2Params` as `Params`, and both are exported types, but you refer to its members as unexported types. I'll assume it's exported, and capitalize the member variables.

### Conclusion

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/argon2"
)

// Argon2Params are ...
type Argon2Params struct {
    Memory     uint32
    Time       uint32
    Threads    uint8
    SaltLength uint32
    KeyLength  uint32
}

func decodeHash(encodedHash string) (p *Argon2Params, salt, hash []byte, err error) {
    fields := strings.Split(encodedHash, "$")

    if len(fields) != 6 {
        err = errors.New("incorrect hash format")
        return
    }

    var version int

    if _, err = fmt.Sscanf(fields[2], "v=%d", &version); err != nil {
        return
    }

    if version != argon2.Version {
        err = errors.New("argon2 version mismatch")
        return
    }

    p = &Argon2Params{}

    if _, err = fmt.Sscanf(fields[3], "m=%d,t=%d,p=%d", &p.Memory, &p.Time,
        &p.Threads); err != nil {
        return
    }

    salt, err = base64.RawStdEncoding.DecodeString(fields[4])
    p.SaltLength = uint32(len(salt))

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    hash, err = base64.RawStdEncoding.DecodeString(fields[5])
    p.KeyLength = uint32(len(hash))

    return
}

func main() {
    decodeHash("$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=3,p=4$ruDgwQK24h0wGXI87+lVWAbHmgNidUNPVSTdSloOlfM$py20HR7L4K6LllGsZNDbkrbh89x2tIF8JCIG0DAaoi8")
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow! such a detailed answer!  Yes the `Params` is same as `Argon2Params `.